# iOS: How to separate key values in multiple dictionary which is in one array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have`NSDictionary` like this:

```
(
    {
    bp = "158/56";
    dateTime = "05/12/2016 11:51:12 AM";
    doc =         {
        "email_id" = "gkalal64@gmail.com";
        exception = 0;
        gender = Male;
        id = 0;
        "mobile_no" = 8149910113;
        name = Kabadia;
        "profile_id" = 0;
        qualification = MBBS;
        "reg_id" = 100;
        salutation = Mr;
        "wellness_id" = IN8S2D29A2;
    };
    "follow_up" = 14;
    id = 6;
    medicine =         (
        "Injection,Crocin,5,0-1-0,After Meal,2",
        "Powder,churan,10,1-0-0,Before Meal,14",
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no
    );
    patient =         {
        "email_id" = "bishtrohit1989@gmail.com";
        exception = 0;
        gender = Male;
        id = 0;
        "mobile_no" = 8624088776;
        name = kamlesh;
        "profile_id" = 0;
        qualification = "";
        "reg_id" = 101;
        salutation = Mr;
        "wellness_id" = IND16HRR65;
    };
    weight = 47;
}
)
```

I want to display above information like following way:
[image]
But i have no idea about how to do that. i searched for this but i didn't get exactly how to do this.

What i did:

In previous View controller i have displayed multiple prescription title. after click on particular cell, i called this view and i got above response from server, which i want to display like above image.

I have taken `UITableView` on screen for this.

I have taken 1 static custom cell for this.

But i don't know how to do.

Please anyone can solve my issue. help will be appreciable.

Comment: have to taken TableView for this screen?

Comment: yes, i did. but i didn't get how to display all content in that.please help me for this issue...@PiyushRathi

Comment: It'll just be a simple for-loop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate,your help will be appreciable  @ElTomato

Comment: are you displaying one prescription in this screen or multiple?

Comment: In previous View controller i have displayed multiple prescription title. after click on particular cell, i called this view and i got above response from server,which i want to display like above image..how to do that, any idea..@PiyushRathi

Comment: @SurajSukale yes, by Selecting one cell you have one dict from array right?

Comment: What you have is a JSON dataset.  You don't put raw integers or float values in Objective-C arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: may i know the reason for downvote the question?

Comment: @SurajSukale is your issue solved?

Comment: No.. please check my updated question.. @PiyushRathi

Comment: let me know, after click on view prescription you are calling web service and got above array?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

```
if (indexPath.row < responseArray.count){

   NSString *docName = @"";
   NSString *contact = @"";
   NSString *wellness_id = @"";
   if ([selectedDict valueForKey:@"doc"] != nil){

        NSDictionary *doctorDict = [selectedDict valueForKey:@"doc"];
        NSString *lDocName = [doctorDict valueForKey:@"name"];
        if(lDocName.length > 0){
            docName = lDocName;
        }

        NSString *qulification = [doctorDict valueForKey:@"qualification"];
        if(qulification.length > 0){
            docName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", docName, qulification];
        }

        NSString *mobile_no = [doctorDict valueForKey:@"mobile_no"];
        if(mobile_no.length > 0){
            contact = mobile_no;
        }

        NSString *email_id = [doctorDict valueForKey:@"email_id"];
        if(email_id.length > 0){
            contact = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", contact, email_id];
        }
        NSString *wellness_idTemp = [doctorDict valueForKey:@"wellness_id"];
        if(wellness_idTemp.length > 0){
            wellness_id= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wellness_Id : %@", wellness_idTemp];
        }
  }
  cell.docNameLabel.text = docName;
  cell.contact.text = contact;
  cell.wellnessID.text = wellness_id;

   NSString *patientName = @"";
   NSString *patientcontact = @"";
   NSString *patientWellness_id = @"";
   NSString *bloodPressure = [selectedDict valueForKey:@"bp"];
   NSString *weight = [selectedDict valueForKey:@"weight"];

  if ([selectedDict valueForKey:@"patient"] != nil){

        NSDictionary *patientDict = [selectedDict valueForKey:@"patient"];
        NSString *lName = [patientDict valueForKey:@"name"];
        if(lName.length > 0){
            patientName = lName;
        }

        NSString *mobile_no = [patientDict valueForKey:@"mobile_no"];
        if(mobile_no.length > 0){
            patientcontact = mobile_no;
        }

        NSString *email_id = [patientDict valueForKey:@"email_id"];
        if(email_id.length > 0){
            patientcontact = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", contact, email_id];
        }
        NSString *wellness_idTemp = [patientDict valueForKey:@"wellness_id"];
        if(wellness_idTemp.length > 0){
            patientWellness_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wellness Id : %@", wellness_idTemp];
        }
   }
    cell.patientNameLabel.text = patientName;
    cell.contact.text = patientcontact;
    cell.wellnessID.text = wellness_id;
    cell.bp.text = bloodPressure;
    cell.weight.text = weight;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: after click on view prescription i am calling web service and got above response

Comment: @SurajSukale so you can take dict at index 0 from response Array and show in your tableview as above.

Comment: i stored my response like _arr=[NSArray arrayWithArray:ResponseArray]; and then in -(UITableViewCell *)tableview----- method, i use like NSDictionary *content = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but i got null,when i print content...... means in ur code,selecteddict is null

Comment: @SurajSukale have you debug it? `_arr` is having count 1? and it is proper

Comment: @SurajSukale i thought error is in response, just don't provide static count 1 in `numberOfRows` function, let pass `_arr` count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130405/discussion-between-piyush-rathi-and-suraj-sukale).

Comment: @SurajSukale is your issue resolved then please upvote answer

Answer (score 2):

As per your data structure i guess your data is kind of single object so it's clear that its not a collection(array) of same kind of object so i would suggest you to create only single custom cell for this entire single record.

In this case your `TableView` will have only single row.

**In the Custom cell:**  lets call it 'PatientDetail'

- Add all the labels and controls which you want to show for each
  property and connect outlets whatever is required.
- If you are using an Autolayout then give relative constraints to all the controls else set frame of each control dynamically by calculating the height of it's content.

**How it will work ?**

As you said its detail screen of particular list so we will show single row in tableview with all the details in it.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

In the follwing code

`responseDict` the `NSDictionary` which is the first object of response as your response is kind of array.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    PatientDetail *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PatientDetail" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Setting
    [cell.lbDateTime setText:[responseDict valueForKey:@"dateTime"]];
    //Doctor name Just
    [cell.lbDoctorName setText:[[responseDict objectForKey:@"doc"]valueForKey:@"name"]];

    //Follow the above steps for all the details



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i stored my response like         _arr=[NSArray arrayWithArray:ResponseArray];  and then in -(UITableViewCell *)tableview----- method, i use like     NSDictionary *content = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  but i got null,when i print content.... what's the issue.. @Mahesh

Comment: @SurajSukale are you following my answer ?

Comment: yes,no problem in your answer but i got null value at content.

Comment: Ok. Don't use indexPath.row now as we have only single record. So use `NSDictionary *content = [_arr objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: You must return 1 from `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: i changed NSDictionary *content = [_arr objectAtIndex:0] this, but same result... content is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130419/discussion-between-mahesh-and-suraj-sukale).